# Push of Undefined in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make a code that looks like this:

```
let number_array: number[]

for(let i=0; i<10; i++){
  number_array.push(i) 
}

console.log("output: ",number_array);
```

So, every time the loop runs it should update the number_array and I should get a value on each iteration.

Output that I want is like:

```
i=0
output: [0]
i=1
output: [0,1]
...
```

I do not know if the way I am trying is correct or not. But please help me to get an output in similar way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply didn't initialize a value for the `number_array` variable :)

You declared the variable and its type, but didn't put the initial value for it (empty array).

Write this instead:

```
let number_array: number[] = [];
```

Comment: @ArthemArkhipov Thanks a lot. Now it is working fine :)